# Serialize multiple attributes with ActiveRecord in one declaration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model with about 10 attributes that I wish to have serialized as `JSON` in my DB.

Is there a way to do:

```
serialize attribute1, JSON
// ...
serialize attribute10, JSON
```

In a single line? Because `serialize [attribute1, ..., attribute10], JSON` doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can probably do something like %w(attr1 attr2 attr3).each {|attr| serialize attr, JSON}

Comment: This helped, thank you. Also, zeantsoi, I am aware how SO works, none of the answers were good and I only had a chance to try user1376019's recommendation this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was the following, as per `user1376019` recommendation:

```
json_exclusions = ["id", "column_not_serialized"]
YourModel.column_names.reject{|col| json_exclusions.include?(col)}.each{|attr| serialize attr, JSON}
```

I went this route because the majority of the attributes for the model I'm working with are serialized, but you  may find listing the serialized attributes directly to be more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

Depending what you're trying to do here, you might actually be better suited by [store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html):

```
store :settings, accessors: :attr1, :attr2, :attr3
```

Rails will use a single column to store (and serialize) multiple attributes, AND it will define accessors for each of them so you can still access them like they're individual columns.

The reason I propose this is because it's relatively unlikely you're getting any additional value from using separate columns in the database as most relational databases don't do anything special with it. Your application is more efficient and you don't have to keep adding columns to your DB when you add another item that needs to be handled similarly.

I use this pattern to store social urls related to a user. When the next network comes along I just add an accessor and a form field and we're set, no migration needed.

---

By the way, Rails 4 also supports specifying the encoder used. I.e.:

```
store :settings, accessors: [ :attr1, :attr2, :attr3 ], coder: JSON
```

Comment: Except it's not *exactly* what I'm looking for. Will definitely use this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not sure this is possible out of the box according to the documentation:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

Otherwise, you can probably create a module which overrides ActiveRecord and does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the  convenience is really worth it to you, you can define a new method to handle this more elegantly:

```
module SerializeAll
  def serialize_all(*columns)
    store = columns.last.is_a?(Module) ? columns.pop : JSON

    columns.each do |column|
      serialize column, store
    end
  end
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend SerializeAll
  serialize_all :attr1, :attr2, :attr3, JSON
end
```

This has the same arity as `serialize` if you consider the splat, but is also somewhat confusing. Another way of implementing `serialize_all` that's more consistent with a lot of other methods in Ruby (and Rails) is to use `extract_options!` which will pull a hash off the end of the array if it is present:

```
def serialize_all(*columns)
  options = columns.extract_options!
  # ... serialize(column, options[:store])
end

serialize_all :attr1, :attr2, :attr3, store: JSON
```

Mostly just a matter of preference. You could also, provided you're using this elsewhere in your application, go ahead and include it into `ActiveRecord::Base`.